# The codenameone is Not Showing Local Notification

Tags: android, codenameone

I want to display local notifications using `codenameone`.

I have imported local notification and it's not showing any error; however, the notification did not popped out!

This is the code :

```
public void start() {
    LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
    n.setId("demo-notification");
    n.setAlertBody("It's time to take a break and look at me");
    n.setAlertTitle("Break Time!");
    n.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_beep-01a.mp3");
    // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

    Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
            n,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
            LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
    );
    Form hi = new Form();
    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right syntax for the alert sound. Did you run it on the device and minimized the app to see if it works.